# Why does this RSpec example require "let!" instead of "let"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I was able to make the test work with the following code, but it seems to be weird and I don't totally understand it.

Can somebody tell me if creating the objects this way is the optimal one?

Why do I have to only use `let!` for the 2nd `post_comment_reply` creation and why don't I for the rest of the objects?

post_comment.rb

```
belongs_to :post, touch: true
belongs_to :user
has_many :post_comment_replies, dependent: :destroy
has_many :users, through: :post_comment_replies

def send_post_comment_reply_creation_notification(reply)
  post_repliers = ([user] + [post.user] + users).uniq - [ reply.user ]
  post_repliers.each do |replier|
    Notification.create(recipient_id: replier.id, sender_id: reply.user_id, notifiable: self.post, action: "commented")
  end
end
```

post_comment_spec.rb

```
describe "instance methods" do
  let(:post_user) { create(:user) }
  let(:comment_user) { create(:user) }
  let(:reply_user) { create(:user) }
  let(:reply_user_2) { create(:user) }
  let(:post_reader) { create(:user) }
  let(:post) { create(:post, user: post_user) }
  let(:post_comment) { create(:post_comment, user: comment_user) }
  let(:post_comment_reply) { create(:post_comment_reply, post_comment: post_comment, user: reply_user) }
  let!(:post_comment_reply_2) { create(:post_comment_reply, post_comment: post_comment, user: reply_user_2) }


  it "send_post_comment_reply_creation_notification" do
    expect{
      post_comment.send_post_comment_reply_creation_notification(post_comment_reply)
    }.to change{Notification.count}.by(3)
  end

end
```

Comment: Something unexplained is happening here. `let!` creates `post_comment_reply_2` before the `it` block runs. How does it affect the expectation? How does the test fail if you delete `post_comment_reply_2`?

Comment: Count changes by 2 instead of the expected 3.

Comment: It doesn't make sense that creating `post_comment_reply_2` *before* the test would affect its result. `change` will look at `Notification.count` at the beginning of the `it` block, after `post_comment_reply_2` is created. How does `post_comment_reply_2` contribute to the change?

Comment: The method sends the notification to all the users who replied to a given `post_comment`. Since both replies belong to the same `post_comment` I think this is the desired outcome. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: I just wasn't clear on the object relationships. I understand now, so I could correctly write the answer I had in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`let` is lazy. If you don't reference it, it doesn't get evaluated and, in your case, side effects don't happen (side effect being the creation of database entry).

`let!`, on the other hand, is always evaluated.

Comment: Sergio, could you explain with this code? I mean why the 2nd reply has to be evaluated before and why the rest doesn't?

Comment: @SzilardMagyar: you use `post_comment_reply` in your test. It is evaluated before the logic you're testing. And it leads to evaluation of most other lets, because they're its dependencies. If you used `post_comment_reply_2` too, you wouldn't have to `let!` it, `let` would also work.

Comment: Ahh, so what is invoked in this part `expect{ post_comment.send_post_comment_reply_creation_notification(post_comment_reply) }`, can be used with `let`, but the rest that's needed to get the correct result with `change{Notification.count}.by(3)` must be evaluated with `let!`?

Comment: That's one way to do this, yes. Alternatively, you can use `before` block for your mandatory side-effects.

Comment: Do you find this solution good enough, or my approach is screwed up when it comes to creating the necessary objects?

Comment: I normally `let` the things I use in my tests, yes. So your code looks fine. Didn't read too closely, though.

Answer (score 1):

**Why you need a `let!`:** `let` is lazy (it runs only when referred to); `let!` is eager (it runs before the test whether referred to or not). Your test needs to create `:post_comment_reply` twice; the `let` one works because the test refers to it, but the `let!` one isn't referred to so it has to be a `let!`, not a `let`.

**Is it optimal?** Your test setup works, but as we discovered it's not as clear as it could be. It also sets a trap for anyone adding more tests to the `describe` block that contains the `let!`: that object will be created before every test whether it's needed or not, slowing down all tests and possibly affecting the results.

Instead, I'd delete the `let!` and write this (`let`s not shown):

```
describe '#send_post_comment_reply_creation_notification' do
  it "notifies each user who replies to the post_comment" do
    create(:post_comment_reply, post_comment: post_comment, user: reply_user_2)
    expect { post_comment.send_post_comment_reply_creation_notification(post_comment_reply) }.
      to change { Notification.count }.by(3)
  end
end
```

In general, prefer creating factory objects in examples (`it` blocks) rather than in `let!` blocks. In fact, prefer creation in examples to `let` as well, unless you're actually using the `let` variable in more than one example. (You only showed one example, but I suspect there are really more in the same `describe` block.) If you're only using a factory object in one test there is no reason to make the reader hunt around your test file for where it's defined, or to define a name available in other tests whether it's used there or not.

Comment: Thanks Dave! It makes sense now!